# Julia Markdown - Chunk Output as Markdown

Tags: julia, markdown

I would like to print a table in Julia Markdown. To the best of my knowledge there is no cool package, yet, that is doing this. Hence, I would like to create a nice looking table through code, but I can't figure out how.

This is my table code...

````
---
title: Just a test
author: Me
date: 2022-01-03
output: pdf_document
---

```julia 
"""
| Column One | Column Two | Column Three |
|:---------- | ---------- |:------------:|
| Row `1`    | Column `2` |              |
| *Row* 2    | **Row** 2  | Column ``3`` |
"""
```
````

...and I want it to produce this...

[image]

...instead of this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Markdown standard library can parse tables too:

```
julia> tbl = """
       | Column One | Column Two | Column Three |
       |:---------- | ---------- |:------------:|
       | Row `1`    | Column `2` |              |
       | *Row* 2    | **Row** 2  | Column ``3`` |
       """
julia> md = Markdown.parse(tbl);

julia> # text formatting like emphasis and bold are lost in pasting
       # to StackOverflow, but shown in the original output
       md

  Column One Column Two Column Three
  –––––––––– –––––––––– ––––––––––––
  Row 1        Column 2             
  Row 2           Row 2   Column 3
```

The parse output is a `Markdown.MD` object that is rendered appropriately depending on your output display (i.e. terminal, Jupyter, etc).

[image: Table as rendered in Pluto]

If you want to produce a markdown table directly from data (without parsing it from a string), you can also construct a `Markdown.Table` directly; check the `varinfo()` function from the `InteractiveUtils` standard library for an example of that.

Comment: This works great in the REPL, but it does not work in a `jmd` document. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: OMG - I take everything back. I made a mistake and it actually does work in the `jmd` as well. Thanks.
(Only thing left would be to write a little package that formats tables for me.)

Comment: @Georgery What kind of package do you mean? Do you mean to create this Markdown table syntax programmatically? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.